# How to draw a nice bar with grid lines in background?

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, matlab-figure, gridlines

I need help to plot the results in 2 bar graphs (with different colours). The resulting figure needs to have grid lines.

How to output a nice plot?

The data is as follows:
x-axis is speed from 2 to 50 and the increment is 2.

```
A = [2.2214523, 1.81357174, 1.61390754, 1.47970432, 1.29658232, 1.26972206, 1.16870602, 1.17688473, 1.30224695, 1.23878984, 1.18680971, 1.26357444, 1.14138904, 0.95115584, 1.16134491, 1.021687, 0.98920929, 1.04342079, 0.99826255, 0.8655728, 0.91652594, 0.85538917, 0.78884521, 0.91927867, 0.86419587]    
B = [187.579709, 25.312399, 11.3572375, 9.3078819, 8.37157321, 7.66729673, 7.36497776, 6.96170053, 6.69527653, 6.77668306, 6.19491326, 6.01744432, 5.61383228, 5.59616954, 5.26652168, 5.26946343, 5.19543014, 5.11049461, 5.05088231, 4.917285, 4.9581181, 4.78929521, 4.772158, 4.7373291, 4.81629734]
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: I tried to search, I got bad figures so I asked help

Comment: Read the [doc](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) everything is well explained. If your problem is more about "using" matlab, you should at least read the ["getting started with matlab"](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html)